# Disabling and Modifying Text in One in an Array of HTML <button> Tags

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a JavaScript theme switcher. When a user clicks on one of the buttons, the style sheet and a few images change. I would like to add functionality that will disable the button for the current theme and add `(current)` to the HTML between the `button` tags. I am trying to compare text in the style sheet name (i.e. "01_Red/") to the index of my array of buttons. The button will change the theme, but the button will not be disabled nor will anything be added to the button text.

**HTML:**

```
<button id="BTN_Red" type="button" class="btn btn-block ThemeBtn RedBtn" onclick="BTN_Red_Click()">Red</button>
<button id="BTN_Scarlet" class="btn btn-block ThemeBtn ScarletBtn" onclick="BTN_Scarlet_Click(); return false;">Scarlet</button>
<button id="BTN_Vermillion" class="btn btn-block ThemeBtn VermillionBtn" onclick="BTN_Vermillion_Click(); return false;">Vermillion</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var btnRed = document.getElementById('BTN_Red');
var btnScarlet = document.getElementById('BTN_Scarlet');
var btnVermillion = document.getElementById('BTN_Vermillion');

var themes = [btnRed, btnScarlet, btnVermillion
];

var numbers = [1, 2, 3];

var logo = document.getElementById('IMG_Logo');
//More images below...

function switchTheme(themeNum, themeColor) {
    stylesheet.href = '../App_Themes/' + themeNum + '_' + themeColor + '/' + themeColor + '.css';
    logo.src = '../App_Themes/' + themeNum + '_' + themeColor + '/Web_Witch_Logo_' + themeColor + '.png';
    // More images that will be changed

    for (var i = 0; i <= themes[i]; i++) {
        if (stylesheet.href.indexOf(numbers[i]) === themes[i+1]) {
            themes[i].disabled = true;
            themes[i].innerHTML + ' <small>(current)</smal>';
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please debug the code to check whether the loop is hit or not?

Comment: Where are your definition of variable `stylesheet`, `logo`, `themes` and `numbers`? please give us a more clear picture of what you've done.

Answer (score 0):

Without more code from your JavaScript (your pasted code has some undefined variables) I see only this solution:

**HTML**

```html
<button id="BTN_Red" type="button" class="btn btn-block ThemeBtn RedBtn" data-themeColor="red" data-themeNum="01">Red</button>
<button id="BTN_Scarlet" class="btn btn-block ThemeBtn ScarletBtn" data-themeColor="scarlet" data-themeNum="02">Scarlet</button>
<button id="BTN_Vermillion" class="btn btn-block ThemeBtn VermillionBtn" data-themeColor="vermillion" data-themeNum="03">Vermillion</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
var themeButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".ThemeBtn");

for (i = 0; i < themeButtons.length; i++) {
  themeButtons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    switchTheme(this.dataset.themenum, this.dataset.themecolor);
  });
}

function switchTheme(themeNum, themeColor) {
  stylesheet.href = '../App_Themes/' + themeNum + '_' + themeColor + '/' + themeColor + '.css';
  logo.src = '../App_Themes/' + themeNum + '_' + themeColor + '/Web_Witch_Logo_' + themeColor + '.png';
  // More images that will be changed

  var themes = document.querySelectorAll(".ThemeBtn");

  for (var i = 0; i < themes.length; i++) {
    if (themes[i].dataset.themecolor == themeColor) {
      themes[i].disabled = true;
      themes[i].innerHTML = themes[i].innerHTML + ' <small>(current)</small>';
    } else {
      themes[i].disabled = false;
      themes[i].innerHTML = themes[i].innerHTML.replace(" <small>(current)</small>", "");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand:

```
<script>
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  span.innerHTML = 'current';
  var btn = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
  console.log(btn[0]);
  for(var i=0;i < btn.length; ++i) {
    btn[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      for(var j=0;j < btn.length; ++j) {
        btn[j].removeAttribute('disabled');
      }
      this.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
      this.append(span);
    })
  }
</script>
```

this js code set attribute `disabled` to button that was clicked and append a span with text `current`